# Use Raphael js to draw directly over google maps

Tags: javascript, maps

How can i use raphael js to draw directly over google maps ? When I draw something over the map it have background, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Havent worked much with Raphael js but found this.

[Mixing Google Maps with Raphael JS (I)](http://scriptstress.blogspot.in/2010/03/mixing-google-maps-with-raphael-js-i.html)

[Google Maps, Raphael JS and browsers](http://scriptstress.blogspot.in/2010/03/google-maps-raphael-js-and-browsers.html)

Also try having a look at  [Cartographer](http://cartographer.visualmotive.com/) ,it uses Raphel JS

Also a discussion over Google group  [Raphael Overlay](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/swOSMcDnaVY/BmNboCQzh0IJ)